# Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ClientID_insert, Line 32 The multi-part identifier "inserted.ID" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create an update trigger that will update the table row with generated the clientid.It uses a sequence and function. I seem to be getting the error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ClientID_insert, Line 32
> The multi-part identifier "inserted.ID" could not be bound

I have tried to look for a solution but i have failed, find below

```
CREATE TRIGGER ClientID_insert
ON [dbo].[tblClient]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE  @Sequence BIGINT =  NEXT VALUE FOR MYSeq
    
    UPDATE tblClient 
    SET tblClient.ClientID = dbo.ClientNo(@Sequence)
    WHERE tblClient.ID = inserted.ID
END
```

Comment: If you want to refer to column from the `inserted` pseudo table, you need to **use that** table in your `UPDATE` statement - e.g. in a `FROM` or `INNER JOIN` clause

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh Its SQL server 2014

Comment: What happens when someone inserts two rows? Is it expected? `INSERT dbo.tblClient() VALUES(row one),(row two);` - do you want them both to get the same sequence value?

Comment: Why don't you just use a default value `ALTER TABLE tblClient ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ClientID DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR MySeq) FOR ClientID`